# Can color-blind people see the effect of combining red, green, and blue light beams?

Tags: physiology, vision, human-eye

When combined, red, green, and blue light beams result in white light. This effect is observed by most of us, but can color-blind people also see this effect?

Comment: There are many kinds of colour blindless, and most kinds aren't black/white.

Comment: Remember the comments on your previous version of this question? Please include your research when posting.